# VisualVM Reporting

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm

I am performing load test on JMeter for webbased application, and i have to get CPU Utilization, Memory Utilization, number of Threds. For this i am using VisualVM. Is there any way we can get as Report in the form of XLS or CSV or any other format we can give to the Customer.

Could you pleasee help me on this or otherwise is there any other Performance tool we can get CPU,Memory utilization?

--
Thanks,
Raghu.ch,

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Tracer plugin](https://dzone.com/articles/visualvm-13) with various probes. Tracer can export data in CSV, HTML or XML.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java VisualVM 1.8, you can generate any of several formats, including CSV, from a snapshot.

[image: Saving snapshot output]

Your CSV file will look something like this:

```
"Class Name - Live Objects";"Live Bytes [%]";"Live Bytes";"Live Objects"
"char[]";"24.76%";"237499352";"1472791"
"byte[]";"12.27%";"117657848";"80945"
...
```

For the specific data you mentioned, it looks like you will need to download one or more of the Tracer plugins that Tomas Hurka mentioned.  You can do this from the Java VisualVM GUI via Tools -> Plugins.

[image: Downloading Tracer plugins]

After restarting the tool, you can save to various formats.

[image: Saving Tracer Output]

Comment: As I checked, the latest available version of Java Visual VM is 1.4.x and not 1.8. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Karri Chandrasekhar - I'm not sure what the disconnect is.  I started C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\jvisualvm.exe.  When I clicked Help->About, it says "Version 1.8.0_172".  Where did you find the 1.4.x listed as the latest version?

Comment: @kc2001- yes, you are correct, I was under a wrong assumption that Java Visula VM was not a part of JDK and when launched(based on binaries downloaded from Github) it was showing the version as 1.4.4. Please check the attached screen shot.